# The first light picture ever taken!

Tags: meaning, sentence, comprehension

I was reading a passage about 'selfie' and came across this sentence which was written on the back of the first selfie taken by Robert Cornelius in 1839.
**"The first light picture ever taken."**
I can't get the whole meaning. Actually I have a problem with the meaning of 'light' in this sentence.
Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: The phrase *light picture* will cease to be puzzling if one reflects on the etymology of the word *photograph*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two nouns **'light'** and **'picture'** stand in the same relationship as

oil painting
dry-point engraving
pencil sketch

The first noun describes the method of making the picture.

In this case light has been focused onto a prepared surface to make a chemical change which creates the appearance of a portrait.

[National Museums of Scotland](https://www.nms.ac.uk/explore-our-collections/stories/science-and-technology/victorian-photography/victorian-photography/victorian-photographic-techniques/) describe and display some early light pictures.